# Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2008 where to include directories and library files

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I was using DEv C++ and for the project settings there was a section where one could enter the directories he wanted to inlude, and lib files. Is there any way to do that in microsoft visual studio c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up the properties for your project. To set the include folders expand the `C/C++` tree node and select `General`. On that page you should see a setting `Additional Include Directories` set as needed. As far as the lib files, select the `Linker` node and expand it. On the `General` section there is an `Additional Library Directories` where you can specify paths, and then on the `Input` node you can set the lib file names to include.

One important note, you need to set it for each configuration you plan to build or set it for all configurations, this gives the flexibility to be able to set different include paths for debug/release builds. You can change between configurations at the top of the pop-up window where it says Configuration